# Rails Route Scoping to value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with an internationalized rails app using the locale as part of the url.  We only have certain languages translated in the database so it's not meaningful to allow users to access any locale in the url.

For example, we cover english and spanish, so our current `routes.rb` places pretty much everything inside of a `scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|es/ do...` block.  My understanding is that this forces :locale, if it exists, to be one of "en" or "es", which works fine for now.

My concern is that different clients will want the system to support other languages (and only those languages).  They will be responsible for creating the internationalization records which contain locale information.  I'm thinking I'd like to automatically allow locale to be any that is already defined in the database, so I added a class method to Translation (the internationalization record)

`def self.available_locales
   Translation.uniq.pluck(:locale)
 end`

and changed routes.rb to `scope "(:locale)", locale: Translation.available_locales do...` however this just made every route go to `/en/es/the_rest_of_the_url`.

**Is it possible to tell rails that routes must use a locale value from the resulting array from available_locales?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just turn it back into a regex, so it matches your first example:

```
Regexp.new([:en, :es].join("|")) #=> /en|es/
```

Or using your class method (ABMagil's edit):

```
Regexp.new(Translation.available_locales.join("|")) #=> /en|es/
```

Comment: @ABMagil, I've added your edit that was rejected. I used a plain array in my example for clarity, but I don't think there was anything wrong with what you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for that.  The class method is used because the list of available locales is user-editable, so it needs to be live.  That said, rather than having to scan the DB everytime things are routed (as in my suggestion), I'm probably going to end up caching that value somewhere and referencing that in routes.rb

Comment: It wouldn't be evaluated every time; just once as the `routes.rb` is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Advanced Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) for that:

```
# routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", constraints: LocaleConstraint.new

# i.e. /lib/locale_constraint.rb
class LocaleConstraint
  def initialize
    # get available locales from DB or so
    @locales = Locale.all
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @locales.include?(request.params[:locale])
  end
end
```

This way you could also write a backend to manage available locales, etc.